# How to make a functional language compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction, functional-programming, ebnf, parse-tree

I am looking into writing a language and a compiler for it as a summer project, and am having a hard time finding information on how to use a parse tree or BNF/EBNF to program a compier. The overall goal would be to write a compiler that would parse a simplified functional language syntax into c. I am currently planning on writing this compiler in c language, but I wouldn't mind doing it in something else if someone believes that it would be a better idea. (I do want to do this by hand though, without the use of tools like LEX)
For example, if I wanted to create the language `ADD` and defined it's syntax as `(+ 3 4)`, it is easy to generate a EBNF for it:

```
    Program   -> {Function}
    Function  -> Operator Integer Integer
    Operator  -> +
    Integer   -> Digit {Digit}
    Digit     -> 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

and it is even easier to make a parse tree:

```
         Function
             |
     -------------------
     |       |         |
  Operator  Integer  Integer
```

But how would you:

1. Represent the EBNF or parse tree in C
2. Use this data to get valid C code

I feel that if I could see a very simple working example it would be enough to get me started in the right direction. I have a feeling that many of you are going to recommend that I read the `Dragon Book` (seems to be the standard resource for compilers), so I want to let you know that it is already ordered and being shipped. 
Thank you in advance for any light you can shed on this!
-vikingsheepman

Comment: You got it right. C is by far not an ideal language for representing trees and performing tree transforms. I'd recommend to consider using  any language with algebraic data types support and pattern matching. As for implementing functional languages in particular: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/pj-lester-book/

Comment: I recommend searching for "recursive descent parser" which handles LL(1) grammars (it used to be enough for most languages, but e.g. current C++ or C# are a bit more complex). There is sample implementation in C shown at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser
Compared to other kinds of (usually generated) parsers, this one is actually quite readable from the source code.

Comment: @jJ That code snippet was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @SK-logic That looks like a really interesting read. I agree with you that straight C is not even close to ideal for manipulating trees, but I would like to eventually like to play around with handling inline assembly. Would using a language like Standard ML make this much harder?

Comment: @vikingsheepman, it's much easier to handle inline assembly with higher level languages, just as well as with any other semantic features.

Comment: @vikingsheepman What I would do is write your compiler in a much higher level language. You can still *generate* C, so inline assembly is fine (either in your source language, which you pass through to the generated C, or you can generate some assembly as part of your compilation; the only reason you'd need a language with good inline assembly support to implement your compiler is if you want write parts of the *compiler itself* in assembly). If this is just a summer project, using C will force you to spend a much higher fraction of your time on the boring bits, and less on your new language.

Comment: @ben Thanks for the advice. I actually ended up opting to use scheme instead of C. There are some nice tutorials out there, and like you said there is no reason to be spending so much time on the boring bits :)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the dragon book, a way of representing the EBNF is to use enums to group the types of the nodes. For example:

```
typedef enum { StmtK , ExpK} NodeKind;
typedef enum { IfK, AssignK, ... } StmtKind;
typedef enum { OpK, ConstK} ExpKind;

typedef enum { Void, Integer } ExpType;
```

and define a Node of the tree this way

```
typedef struct treeNode {
    struct treeNode * child[MAXCHILDREN];
    struct treeNode * sibling;
    int lineNo;
    NodeKind nodekind;
    union { StmtKind stmt; ExpKind exp; } kind; //Use union to save space
    union { TokenType op;
            int val;
            char * name; } attr;
    ExpType type; //To verify expression types
} TreeNode;
```

There is still a long way to generate the C code, but essentially you need to do some checks over the generated tree (syntax, semantics...) and then generate the code. How to do it depends on the type of compiler you are building (one or more pass). If you ordered the Dragon Book, for sure you will find all of this there.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly for the `ADD` language I proposed in my post I would make a tree as you have posted using the enumerators `typedef enum {ExpK} NodeKind;` (language only has expressions) `typedef enum {OpK} ExpKind;` (for the '+' operator) and `typedef enum {Integer} ExpType;` (only possible expression return) ? Or am I way off base here?